# Any special class of numbers other than 2^n for which Collatz is true?

Tags: number-theory, dynamical-systems

The title says it all.
Are there any special class of numbers other than $2^n$ for which [Collatz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture) is true? (I mean numbers such as other powers? or some other formula that is in essence not a manipulation of $2^n$. )

Thanks.

Comment: All numbers less than $20 × 2^{58} $, if that counts...

Comment: Trivially, $2^nk$ for any fixed $k$ known to satisfy the conjecture.

Answer (score 2):

By the work of [Ştefan Andrei, Manfred Kudlek, Radu Ştefan Niculescu](http://www.mendeley.com/research/some-results-collatz-problem/), there are some more infinite sets of numbers for which the conjecture holds. There was a related question on MO [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/51124/collatz-conjecture-for-numbers-of-th-form-2n-1).

**P.S.** :Currently, the server I am using requires a subscription. I hope I will explain the details at a later date. If someone has access, please help.